# Get file tags in VBA using variable file name

Tags: vba

I'm using VBA in Excel to loop through a series of files and decide which ones to import. I'd like to decide which files to import using something like the file's tags, so that I don't need to open every single file. I'm trying to use the `GetDetailsOf` method to get them, but it's failing whenever I try to use a variable for the file name.

This code, using a Constant for the file name, works correctly:

```
Sub TestTags()
  Dim strPath As String
  Dim strFile As String

  strPath = "C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Safe Space\MacroTest\"
  strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
  Do While strFile <> ""
      Debug.Print GetTags()
      strFile = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub

Function GetTags()
  Const csFile As String = "MyTestFile.xlsx"

  With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Safe Space\MacroTest\")
      GetTags = .GetDetailsOf(.Items.Item(csFile), 18)
  End With
End Function
```

However, when I try to replace the constant with a variable passed by the calling subroutine, I get an error. Here is the failing code:

```
Sub TestTags()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String

    strPath = "C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Safe Space\MacroTest\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Debug.Print GetTags(strFile)
        strFile = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub

Function GetTags(ByVal strFile As String)
    Const csFile As String = "MyTestFile.xlsx"
    Dim i As Integer

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Safe Space\MacroTest\")
        GetTags = .GetDetailsOf(.Items.Item(strFile), 18)
    End With
End Function
```

The only thing I'm changing is the argument in the `.GetDetailsOf` method, switching from a constant to a variable. Whenever it runs, it stops on that line with 'Error 445: Object doesn't support this action'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try passing `strPath & strFile` to GetTags instead of just strFile.  I mean you can pass it as a literal concatenation, you don't necessarily have to pass it as two parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

OK. Still can't work out precisely why case 2 doesn't work, but I *have* found that the "proper" way to get the FolderItem object corresponding to `strFile` (as required by `.GetDetailsOf()`) is to use the `.ParseName()` method:

```
Function GetTags(ByVal strFile As String)
    Const csFile As String = "MyTestFile.xlsx"
    Dim i As Integer

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Safe Space\MacroTest\")
        GetTags = .GetDetailsOf(.ParseName(strFile)), 18)
    End With
End Function
```

---

I can't explain *why* it doesn't work, but I do have three work-arounds.

1) Use `CStr(strFile)` instead of `strFile` when calling `.GetDetailsOf()`:

```
Function GetTags(ByVal strFile As String)
    Const csFile As String = "MyTestFile.xlsx"
    Dim i As Integer

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Safe Space\MacroTest\")
        GetTags = .GetDetailsOf(.Items.Item(CStr(strFile)), 18)
    End With
End Function
```

or

2) Change the parameter type of `strFile` to `Variant`:

```
Function GetTags(ByVal strFile As Variant)
    Const csFile As String = "MyTestFile.xlsx"
    Dim i As Integer

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Safe Space\MacroTest\")
        GetTags = .GetDetailsOf(.Items.Item("" & strFile), 18)
    End With
End Function
```

or

3) Concatenate a null string to `strFile` when calling `.GetDetailsOf()`:

```
Function GetTags(ByVal strFile As Variant)
    Const csFile As String = "MyTestFile.xlsx"
    Dim i As Integer

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Safe Space\MacroTest\")
        GetTags = .GetDetailsOf(.Items.Item("" & strFile), 18)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Okay, that's just...crazy. Why would that work?!  It's closer, but something's still off...instead of returning "Imported 188", as it does when I use a constant, it's returning "Tags", the name of the category rather than its content.

Comment: @Werrf Added a third work-around. I'm still puzzled by why it doesn't work and even more so why the work-arounds even manage to by-pass the error.

Comment: @Werrf Not sure what you're doing differently, but all three work-arounds are working on my end. I'm running on Excel 2007, though.

Comment: Got it - I had tried passing the full path to `strFile` to see if that made a difference. When I passed the full path, it gave me `Tags` as the result, but when I passed it just the file name it gave me the content of the tag, `Imported 188`. Working, thank you!

Comment: @Werrf I think I know what the problem is. You should be using `strFile` instead of `.Items.Item(strFile)` when calling `.GetDetailsOf()`. Still trying to nail down the precise details, but it seems that `.Items` doesn't have a "proper" `.Item` method and fails sometimes. You can use either a FolderItem object or a string for the argument to `.GetDetailsOf` so using a string should solve the problem. I might try a bit more research and then update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works for me in Excel 2010 :

```
Dim fdata as String
Dim ffolder as String
Dim filename as String
Dim foldobj As Object
Dim fshell As Object
Dim fullpath As String

Set fshell = CreateObject("shell.application") 
ffolder = "M:\AVMEDIA\FOLDER01"
filename = "video.mp4"
fullpath = ffolder & "\" & filename
Set foldobj = fshell.Namespace(ffolder & "\")
fdata = foldobj.GetDetailsOf(foldobj.ParseName(filename), 18)
```

COMMENTS

1. The trailing backslash when creating the folder object is essential. MS documentation appears to be incorrect.
2. The object whose details we parse to get our data is the file name, NOT the full path. This is per MS documentation.
3. The whole business of what data is stored in which file tag is unspeakably horrible, especially if you have more than one file type.

Answer (score -1):

The Dir() function does NOT return a full path, it only returns the filename and extension.  Therefore, when you try to access the tags, you're only passing the filename and extension if you get the result of Dir().  Instead, pre-pend the path as shown below.  I changed the name of the passed variable in GetTags to help avoid confusion.

```
Sub TestTags()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String

    strPath = "C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Safe Space\MacroTest\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Debug.Print GetTags(strPath & strFile)
        strFile = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub

Function GetTags(ByVal strFullPath As String)
    With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Safe Space\MacroTest\")
        GetTags = .GetDetailsOf(.Items.Item(strFullPath), 18)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: No change. Note that in the code that works, the constant also only contains the file name.

Comment: In your code that works, you define `csFile` but you never use it that I can see - it still references strFile which declared only in TestFlags().  You also declare an integer i that never gets used.

Comment: That was my oversight, sorry - I must have missed that change when I was copying it. Corrected to show that the working code uses `csFile` in the first argument for `.GetDetailsOf`. The integer i is an artefact from an earlier test I was doing, and can be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

adding + 0 or  & vbnullstring  & "" to a variable to be passed 
in many cases causes an auto conversion to the required type..
Some kind language designer many years ago must have put the routine in there